# How does $\exists N\; \forall\varepsilon>0 \;\forall k > N \; (d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon)$ differ from definition of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show

$\exists N\; \forall\varepsilon>0 \;\forall k > N \;(d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon) \qquad \implies \qquad\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists N\;\forall k > N \;(d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon)$

I get that $\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists N \;\forall k > N \;(d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon)$ is the definition of convergence, and I have no problem proving it either, however I am unsure as to how $\exists N \;\forall \varepsilon >0 \;\forall k > N \;(d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon)$ differs.

I am told that $\exists N \; \forall\varepsilon>0 \;\forall k > N \;(d(x_n,x) < \varepsilon)$ is a stronger statement and that it implies the other, but I am unsure as to why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the order of the quantifies in both definitions

Comment: In "convergence definition" that statement says something like: for every epsilon, u can find N(epsilon). And for every other epsilon that N can differ. In the second statement, it says something like: There is one particular N that is "good" for every epsilon.

Comment: I think the idea here is that the statement on the right implies, that N is dependent on epsilon, and the one on the left implies, that it is not, which makes it stronger.

Comment: The sequence $(1/n)$ converges to $0$, right? But it doesn't satisfy the stronger statement $-$ what on earth could $N$ be?

Answer (score 1):

The convergence definition says that once $\epsilon$ is picked, you can find an index N such that all the terms after the index is in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the limit.

The "if" part of your implication states that you can find an index such that all the terms after are in **every** $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the limit. That could only be true if the tail of the sequence was constant. Otherwise, we could always find $\epsilon$ to make the statement false.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version your N depends  on your $\epsilon$ and it might change from $\epsilon $ to $\epsilon.$

The second case is stronger because it provides an $N$ which is good for every $\epsilon$

The second case implies the first case because your $N$ is already provided and you do not have to solve an equation to find it.